# How Serialization Works in .Net

Tags: .net, serialization, properties

I have a feeling this is a repost but I can't seem to find any good information about it. I was just wondering how serialization actually works (well actually deserialization). What I'm wondering is if say I have a property that is not actually backed by a private field; i.e.:

```
public string SomeProp {
   get {
      return GetValue("SomePropKey");
   }
   set{
      SetValue("SomePropKey", value);
   }
}
```

When I deserialize does the setter get called? The getter gets called on serialization because when I serialize the object the correct value is written to the output stream. I know this seems like a strange circumstance, but what is really going on? Or am I just over complicating this....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It completely depends on the mechanism you are using for serialization.

If you are using XmlSerialization, then yes, the setter gets called.

If you are using data contract serialization (the DataContractSerialization) then the getter/setter will be called if you apply the DataMember attribute to the property (not to its backing field).

If you are using the original serialization mechanism in .NET (IFormatter implementation) then this scenario isn't possible, because it will only serialize values stored in fields.

Comment: Thanks, we are using XmlSerialization. Sorry I didn't include that. And thank you again!

Comment: XmlSerializer serializes the public members and invokes the zero parameter constructor which is annoying because it presumes that what you want to be executed by your business logic when constructing is identical to what you want when deserializing. This might be true of 99% of your classes and that is not good enough. BinaryFormatter.Serialize (and probably SoapFormatter.Serialize) prove this constraint is unnecessary and avoidable and they also do not require you to increase risk because private members are serializable. Unfortunately BinaryFormatter and SoapFormatter are obsolete.

Comment: BinaryFormatter is considered to be a security risk. DataContractSerializer is in my opinion better than XmlSerializer. There is no constraint on the zero parameter constructor so code it as you wish. It is lower risk because data can be private; people looking at serialized XML files not withstanding. DataContract / DataMember attributes are annoying but acceptable.

Comment: DataMember decoration on the set/get field means accessors will be run on serialize/deserialize. I prefer to put the DataMember decoration on the backing store because I do not presume that set/get business logic will always be relevant to serialize/deserialize and deciding it is relevant seems like perpetuating a constraint. There is no need to put the DataMember attribute on both the backing store and the property which might be undocumented because it is obvious or it might be undocumented because the documentation is unpolished.

Comment: More problems with XmlSerializer: it cannot serialize a Dictionary.  If your class implements IEnumerable<T> then XmlSerializer will treat the object as if it is nothing but an enumerable and it will ignore other member data and not serialize them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about XML Serialization, or 'regular' serialization (soap / binary), since -afaik- these 2 serialization techniques differ.

AFAIK, if you use the BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter, the fields are serialized/deserialized, and not the properties.
On deserialization, I believe that the special 2-arg constructor which has the SerializationInfo & StreamingContext arguments is used.

But, nothing hinders you of taking control of the serialization process by implementing the ISerializable interface.
Then, if you want that your value is set using your property, I think you can perfectly do so.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not a direct answer to your question and you have already got the answer you were looking for. But I didn't want to withhold this. You can look at the Base Class Library sources using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). It's an excellent way to understand more about the internals of the .net framework and to broaden your knowledge.